# Playback streaming audio with AVAudioengine (iOS)

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, playback, avaudioengine

I want to stream audio on iOS using `AVAudioEngine`. 
Currently I'm not sure how to do this.

I get RTP data from the network and want to playback this audio data with `AVAudioEngine`.

I am using the iOS `Network.Framework` to receive the network data. 
I then decode the speech data and now want to play it back using `AVAudioEngine`.

Here is my receive code:

```
connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
    if isComplete {

    // decode the raw network data with Audio codec G711/G722
    let decodedData = AudioDecoder.decode(enc: data, frames: 160)

    // create PCMBuffer for audio data for playback
    let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 8000, channels: 1)
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: 160)!
    buffer.frameLength = buffer.frameCapacity

    // TODO: now I have to copy the decodedData --> buffer (AVAudioPCMBuffer)

    if error == nil {
       // recall receive() for next message
       self.receive(on: connection)
    }
}
```

How do I copy the `decodedData` to my `AVAudioPCMBuffer`?
Currently, my `buffer` var is created, but does not contain any data.

Background information:

My general approach would be to cache inside the PCMBuffer with a collection and playback this collection with the `AVAudioEngine`.

Is there a better way consume the audio data directly (instantly)?

Comment: My decoded linear data is cashed in an array from type Int16. So the var **decodedData** is from type [Int16], maybe there is a possibility to consume this data directly? The function **scheduleBuffer** allows only AVAudioPCMBuffer as input.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you've found a solution yet, but I was able to stream audio with AVAudioEngine. I didn't use AudioDecoder but instead streamed packets using URLSession to download packets. Then I streamed these downloaded packets into AudioFileStreamOpen where I formatted audio packets. Finally, I converted these packets into PCM buffers for the engine using AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer and scheduled these buffers into the engine for playback.

Here's my completed project: https://github.com/tanhakabir/SwiftAudioPlayer in which I set up a full engine that I used on my podcast player.
And here's a short blog I wrote about the overall architecture: https://medium.com/chameleon-podcast/creating-an-advanced-streaming-audio-engine-for-ios-9fbc7aef4115

Here's the blog I based my library on: https://github.com/syedhali/AudioStreamer

Answer (score 0):

try AVAudioConverter

let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)